# 'drv' does not name a type

Tags: c++, namespaces

Been looking for awhile and I cant find an answer. All paths are included. I'm referencing a class in another namespace in the class I'm creating.

I'm getting the following error:
***src/app/Application.h:30:9: error: 'drv' does not name a type***

Code Below. Any help is appreciated!

Main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    app::Application program;

    program.run();

    return 0;
}
```

LEDs.h

```
#ifndef LEDS_H
#define LEDS_H

namespace drv {

    class LEDs {
    public:
        LEDs();
        void InitLEDs(void);
        void SetLEDs(const uint8_t value);
    private:
        static const uint8_t NUM_LEDs = 5;
    };
}

#endif  /* LEDS_H */
```

Application.h

```
#ifndef APPLICATION_H
#define APPLICATION_H

namespace app {

    enum State {
        NORMAL = 0,
        ZONE,
        PAIRING,
        STUCK,
        BATT,
        OFF
    };

    class Application {
    public:
        Application();
        void run(void);
        void execute_loop(void);
    private:
        bool IDLE;
        State STATE;
        drv::LEDs Leds; // LINE 30

    };
}
#endif  // APPLICATION_H
```

Application.cpp

```
#include "stdint.h"
#include "stdbool.h"    
#include "../drv/LEDs.h"
#include "Application.h"

namespace app {

    Application::Application() {
        IDLE = false;
        STATE = NORMAL;
    }

    void Application::run(void) {
        Leds.InitLEDs();

        while(1)
        {
            if(IDLE) {
                PowerSaveIdle();
            }
            else {
                execute_loop();
            }
        }

    }

    void Application::execute_loop(void)
    {

    }

}
```

LEDs.cpp

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "LEDs.h"

namespace drv {
    LEDs::LEDs() { 
    }

    void LEDs::InitLEDs() {
        SetLEDs(0xff);
    }

    void LEDs::SetLEDs(const uint8_t value) {
        //Removed for readability
    }
}
```

Comment: you really should be including `leds.h` in `application.h` (instead of relying on include order somewhere else entirely).

Comment: You don't show any #includes for main.cpp.  But with the reasonable guess that you only #included Application.h but not leds.h.  And thus got the error.

Comment: Our coding standards prevent #include in any header file. However I have tried including the LEDs.h in the headers and got the same error.

Comment: Adding the #include for LEDs.h in main.cpp worked. I'm wondering why this is since it is only being accessed by the Application class?

Comment: Your company's coding standards are insane.  Also, you just accepted an answer that told you to... include the file.  So apparently not.

Comment: @user1785853 `Our coding standards prevent #include in any header file`  `Adding the #include for LEDs.h in main.cpp worked` It's your company's crazy policy to not include headers in .h files, so it stands to reason that you need to include any/all header files in .cpp modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an `#include ...` line in Application.h.  At the top of that file (or just after the inclusion guards) add the line

```
#include "LEDs.h"
```